How close are aircraft allowed to get to each other mid-flight?
I was on an easyJet flight from Antalya to Manchester on the 20th September 2024, flight number 2142. I looked out of the window and saw a green and white coloured plane. I have looked it up and it was a condor airlines. The plane seemed very close to ours and didn’t seem to be over 1000 ft. It was approx 2 hours into the flight but that is a very loose guess. Should it have been that close?

This question is similar to: How much is the minimum safe distance between two planes in-flight?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. -- The linked question is about FAA airspace specifically but there are other similar questions here already, e.g. this one which is about European airspace.

@randomhead Well he's asking for details about his specific flight and whether we could get them. Perhaps it's a bit more case by case than that question.

At the risk of stating the obvious: (1) planes are big, and (2) 1000 feet is a shorter distance than you might think. (It's about 300 meters, or 0.2 miles or the height of the Eiffel Tower or six olympic swimming pools for US readers. ;)) A plane flying past yours at a distance of 1000 feet looks very close, especially in the middle of the sky with nothing else around to compare the distance to.

@IlmariKaronen how many banana is that?

@vasin1987 around 1700-1900 banana depending on their size

It varies but I'm pretty sure nothing wrong has happened during your flight.
Vertical Separation: RVSM (Reduced Vertical Separation Minimum) reduces the standard vertical separation between aircraft from 2,000 feet to 1,000 feet for flights between flight levels 290 and 410 which is 29,000ft to 41,000 (at sea level, flight levels do not account for elevation of the area).
I've checked the FlightRadar24 logs from yesterday of EasyJet Flight 2142 (U22142/EZY98NU).
The closest Condor flight to your EasyJet plane was Condor Flight 1654 (DE1654/CFG7HT) from Leipzig to Kos Island. It was at ~35,000ft when it came near your plane and you were at 36,000ft. It was D-ANMY, a green-stripe livery A321, just as you described.
Image of this plane:

(Source)
It happened around Budapest, Hungary. This is RVSM airspace. The required vertical separation is 1000ft, which was maintained properly here. The planes just almost passed over each other if you are interested in that.
Flightradar24 link for your flight - here and for the Condor flight - here.
They came like this

Before passing like this

If there was anything wrong with the jets that caused them to be too close by the standards, there's TCAS (Traffic collision avoidance system) on all airliners that would alert the pilots very accurately and tell them to climb or descend accordingly.

How did you get all that info? I mean what flight, an image of the Condor flight, the flight number of the Condor flight, the location at which it happened, the departure and destination of the Condor flight, specifics of the aircraft, ...etc all that and in less than an hour? I'm just curious. Great answer, BTW.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 I used Flightradar24 to go to the departure time of that flight in playback. Then I put a filter just for Condor planes, and selected the EasyJet plane. Then with the API I checked the coordinates of the closest planes, this came up, and I used the website to show how it happened. Takes 15 minutes.

Wow, that's superb. So Flightradar24 is open to public?

@AircraftEnthusiast007 yes most features of FR24 are free, there is also a subscription with more functionalities. Another service like that is globe.adsbexchange.com

Thankyou so much for taking the time to look into you have answered it fantastically well and it’s much appreciated

@EddieM if you think this is correct answer you can mark it as correct.

@EddieM Please see this article in the [help]: What should I do when someone answers my question?

thanks for this amazing level of detail, wonderful!

I created an account just to vote this up. Great answer.

@Dave, well I hit the 200 cap today, so your upvote won't give me rep... it doesn't roll over to the next day... thanks anyway!

gold medal answer !
